# 32F746GDISCO Stackup and Ethernet Impedance

Tags: altium, ethernet, impedance-matching, stack-up

I have an example board with PCB about the ethernet application.
I noticed a mismatch between stack up and ethernet lines, or something else I don't know.
Ethernet Lines are drawn with 0.125mm and its gap is set to 0.175mm.
However, when I examine the layer stack up, the line impedance becomes 124 ohms.
Am I doing something wrong?
By the way, the lines were drawn at the top and bottom layers.

[image: stackup]

[image: microstrip]

[image: rules]

Comment: Your calculator doesn't take the solder mask into account

Comment: Should the solder mask be taken into the calculation too?

Comment: Since the two lines are coupled to each other you have significant field lines through the solder mask, thus the solder mask dialectic properties effect the field and needs to be taken into account.

Comment: Well, how can I calculate it with microstrip considering the solder mask?